# start video player with bat file, fail message in the java window

Tags: java

I want to start my java video player with bat file but it's never happening. If I start other program that go smoothly. I can't read message fail because java window close immediatelly...
What would be the problem? How can I read the fail message?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify your bat file. Remove 'start' command to not start new cmd window because I guess you don't need it. If you need stop bat until you prass a key you can add 'pause' command. So your bat could look like below

```
chcp 1250
java VideoPlayer
pause
```

Now maybe you can see any additional message

Comment: OK. That's working. My fail message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/co/caprica/vlcj/runtime/RuntimeUtil at VideoPlayer.main(VideoPlayer.java:23)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381).......

Comment: You need to attach libraries that you use in your code. It is probably named vlcj{something}.jar. Please try to add used library or libraries to your folder with bat file or add it as parameter of java call:  'java VideoPlayer -classpath drive:\folders\library1.jar;drive:\folders\library2.jar' where drive, folders and jars names should be modified to point to libraries that you use

Comment: Thanks your advice! It's working. But I had to modify a bit your command line. VideoPlayer(main class) I had to write after classpath and I had to write the main class folder in the classpath. my command line: java -classpath "drive:\folders\library1.jar;drive:\folders\library2.jar;drive:\folders\mainclasslibrary" VideoPlayer